# I need to download a database with the given details

Tags: sql, database, azure

I've been given some credentials for a database hosted through Azure. I need to download the contents of the database but am not sure where I go from here.

Here are the details provided.

```
define('DB_NAME', '****'); 
define('DB_USER', '****');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '****'); 
define('DB_HOST', 'au-cdbr-azure-southeast-a.cloudapp.net');
```

How do I use this to download what I need?

Thanks

Comment: An azure database is the same as any other. You should be able to connect with anything that can connect to a database - excel for example, but also any sql query tool. I assume you actually have the database, user and password? Also, access to a sql database can be controlled by source ip address - so that must also be opened by the azure admins. I assume that has also been done.

Comment: Hi josh, if my answer helps, can you please accept it? Thanks and have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

You have these Azure SQL database credentials. But if the Azure SQL DB doesn't open the database firewall for you, you can't do anything with it.

It means that you could not connect to the Azure SQL database or download the contents of it.

For more details, please see: [Azure SQL Database and SQL Data Warehouse IP firewall rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure).

If you are added to the database firewall role, you can connect to the Azure SQL database and download it.

Please see: [Export an Azure SQL database to a BACPAC file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export).

Hope this helps.